# вытащить из объекта только нужные свойства

Tags: javascript, json

Имеется объект вида:

```js
var object = {
  id: 1
  position: {},
  lengt: 5,
  childs: {
    id: 1,
    position: {},
    lengt: 5,
    сhilds: { ...
    }
    attributes: {
      id: 2,
      name: "start2"
    },
    posts: {},
  },
  attributes: {
    id: 1,
    name: "start"
  },
  posts: {}
}
```

`childs` является вложенным объектом, в котором хранятся такие же `childs`.

Необходимо вытащить из объекта свойства `object.attributes.name`, `object.attribures.id`, а так же всех `childs` и преобразовать в массив.

В результате

```js
var result = {
  id: 1,
  name: "start",
  childs: [{id: 1, name: "start"} … ]
}
```

Comment: Язык какой? JS?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov да, метка не ставилась

Comment: все исходные childs должны попасть в один массив не зависимо от уровня вложения? Или новый массив childs тоже древовидный?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov из родительского объекта нужно вытащить из атрибутов свойства name и id, а так же для каждого из вложенного объекта child вытащить тоже самое, но хранить всех child в виде массивов, а свойства child так же объхект

Comment: Т.е. всех детей вставить в один массив. И в этот же массив всех внуков. Так?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov ну получается, что да, это будет один массив, который будет содержать всех внуков и детей, а так же их айди и неймы. Массиов объектов

Answer (score 1):

Так?

```js
var object = {
  id: 1,
  position: {},
  lengt: 5,
  childs: {
    id: 1,
    position: {},
    lengt: 5,
    childs: {
      attributes: {
        id: 3,
        name: "start3"
      },
    },
    attributes: {
      id: 2,
      name: "start2"
    },
    posts: {},
  },
  attributes: {
    id: 1,
    name: "start"
  },
  posts: {}
}

function makeObj(obj, childs) {
  if (!obj)
    return;
  childs.push(obj.attributes);
  makeObj(obj.childs, childs);
}

const res = object.attributes;
res["childs"] = [];
makeObj(object.childs, res.childs);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: переработал в нужный вид, да теперь детей он хранит в массиве объектов. И вопросик остался, по какому принципу удалить все ненужные свойства, чтобы остались только name id и childs [] ? просто я решаю эту проблему через delete (обект.свойство)

Comment: @oleja Мой ответ решил вашу проблему?

Comment: не совсем, объект, который был дан вначале имеет немного другой вид:
```var object = {id:1, attributes: {id:1, name: "start" }, child {id:2, attributes: {id:2, name:"start2" }, child:{id:3... }```

Comment: @oleja Я дал ответ для того объекта, который был представлен в вопросе. А навыками телепатии я не обладаю

Comment: Я понял, спасибо, но есть ли возможность словесный алгортм подсказать, чтобы удовлетворяло второму условию ?

Comment: Какому второму условию?

Comment: ```var object = {id:1, attributes: {id:1, name: "start" }, child {id:2, attributes: {id:2, name:"start2" }, child:{id:3... }```, учитывая, у всех эментов чилд может быть несколько и детей и внуков

Comment: @oleja Тогда это невалидный JSON. Имя поля должно быть уникальным. Если нужно несколько детей - используйте массив `child: [{id:2, attributes: {id:2, name:"start2" }}, {id:3... } ...]`